# Cómo pasar está consulta a Java con document la consulta es de mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Una duda Compañeros, estoy iniciando en Java con mongoDB y me surgen algunas dudas al convertir consultas de mongo a Java, alguien que tenga algún manual o algún ejemplo donde use el `$gt` o `$or` en java, este es mi query en mongo "

```
db.tablaEjemplo.find({"REFERENCIA1":"20",_id:{$gt:ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date()-518000000)/1000).toString(16)+"0000000000000000")},"$or":[{"finalizado":{"$exists":false}},{"finalizado":"no"}]}).pretty()"
```

Pero de alguna u otra forma no he podido pasarlo a java.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Acaso has leído la documentación del driver de MongoDB para Java?